# What's a good substitute for ProComm on Linux?

Tags: linux, modem

Is minicom the only option?  I need to be able to modem in to some ancient applications that are commonly accessed by ProComm running on Windows, but I would like to do this from a Linux box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

minicom is the best option, yes.  kermit might also work for you. If you're on an older unix box, you might look for cu.  @Zoredache points out that screen will also [do the trick](http://unixsadm.blogspot.com/2008/01/using-gnu-screen-as-terminal-emulator.html), since serial ports are ttys.

Answer (score 4):

Minicom is probably the best option, but you also can use [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) for making [serial connections](http://unixsadm.blogspot.com/2008/01/using-gnu-screen-as-terminal-emulator.html).